# Not able to write more than 8 characters in file via PUSH command in REXX

Tags: mainframe, rexx

I am writing a code in which if I find 10th character of a line as "C" then I am removing C from there and appending it to next line in ps file. All records in file have 8 characters except one record(could be any record).
Below is my input file in which I am updating:

```
A2f6k1GG C
B3g7l2HH  
C4h8m3II  
D5i9n4JJ
```

Desired output is :

```
A2f6k1GG 
B3g7l2HH C 
C4h8m3II  
D5i9n4JJ
```

My REXX code is :

```
/*REXX*/
TRACE I   
/* READ PASSWORD FILE */                                          
 ADDRESS TSO "ALLOC F(INFILE1) DSN('PPPRG3.PASSWRD.LIST') SHR REU"
/* INFILE1 is a logical name for the file */                      
"EXECIO * DISKR INFILE1 ( FINIS STEM PASSWRD."                    
/* PASSWRD is the stem (array) that holds the data */             
"FREE F(INFILE1)"                                                 
STRING1 = ""                                                      
STRING2 = ""                                                      
/* S12 = STRING1 || " " || STRING2 */                             
J = 1                                                             
DO J = 1 TO PASSWRD.0                                             
   PASSWRD.J = STRIP(PASSWRD.J)                                   
  IF SUBSTR(PASSWRD.J,10,1) = "C" THEN                            
     DO                                                           
       STRING1 = SUBSTR(PASSWRD.J,1,8)                            
       Y = J +1                                                   
       STRING2 = PASSWRD.Y                                        
       SAY STRING1 STRING2                                        
       ST3 = STRIP(STRING2,"B"," ") || " C"                        
       SAY ST3                                                       
       ADDRESS TSO  "ALLOC DA('PPPRG3.PASSWRD.LIST') F(updatedd) OLD"
       "EXECIO 1 DISKRU updatedd "J" (LIFO"                          
       PULL line                                                     
       PUSH STRING1                                                  
       "EXECIO 1 DISKW updatedd"                                     
       SAY "UPDATE1"                                                 
       "EXECIO 1 DISKRU updatedd "Y" (LIFO"                          
       PULL line                                                     
       PUSH ST3                                              
       "EXECIO 1 DISKW updatedd (FINIS"                              
       SAY "UPDATE2"                                                 
       "FREE F(updatedd)"                                            
     END                                                             
  ELSE                                                               
     J = J + 1                                                       
END
```

Output I am receiving is :

```
A2f6k1GG 
B3g7l2HH  
C4h8m3II  
D5i9n4JJ
```

Comment: My input file was in VB format. When I changed it to FB , it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a note in the manual on EXECIO and DISKW. So it works as designed.

*The length of an updated line is set to the length of the line it replaces. When an updated line is longer than the line it replaces, information that extends beyond the replaced line is truncated. When information is shorter than the replaced line, the line is padded with blanks to attain the original line length.*